# how free text search works in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

i am working on a project in which i have to implement free text using postgresql database, i am not able to understand that how it can work by just using @@ instead of like command.

i have a table

```
Employee
- Id
- Name
- Location
- ManagerName

//my query was

select * from Employee where name @@ 'xxx'
```

i am searching on name as free text and it gives result, can nay one tell me where is the index or search catalogue, as i didn't  made and configuration etc but its still working.

any chance postgresql do it for all the  tables or it created a catalogue on runtime?

can any one tell me how it works?

Comment: If you want to learn about full text search, read this read it carefully: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch.html

Comment: thanks, i have gone through the documents, i am more confused after reading it

Comment: @rajansoft1 Did you read the whole chapter on Full Text Search in 15 minutes? Maybe you need to study it more?

Answer (score 1):

### What's actually happening

If you look at the operators defined for `@@` you'll see that there are a few variants with different data types. They're all *overloads* for the same operator.

```
regress=> \do @@
                                        List of operators
   Schema   | Name | Left arg type | Right arg type | Result type |         Description          
------------+------+---------------+----------------+-------------+------------------------------
 pg_catalog | @@   | text          | text           | boolean     | text search match
 pg_catalog | @@   | text          | tsquery        | boolean     | text search match
 pg_catalog | @@   | tsquery       | tsvector       | boolean     | text search match
 pg_catalog | @@   | tsvector      | tsquery        | boolean     | text search match
```

Now, if you do `a @@ b` where `a` and `b` are both `text` fields (or `varchar`, which gets converted to text), it calls a the `@@(text, text)` operator.

This *converts the inputs automatically* into text search token lists, then compares them.

So it's basically shorthand for `to_tsvector(a) @@ to_tsquery(b)`. Which is why it works.

See, there are two parts to fulltext search: the comparison operations with tsearch vectors and queries that do all the fancy wildcards and stemming, and the index support.

What you're using here is the comparison part, but not the index. The index can make it *faster*, but doesn't add *features*.

### Step by step

So this still works:

```
regress=> SELECT 'frightening' @@ 'frightened';
 t
(1 row)
```

because it's really basically converting both sides then using the `@@(tsvector,tsquery)` operator, like:

```
regress=> SELECT to_tsvector('frightening') @@ to_tsquery('frightened');
 t
(1 row)
```

It's using the globally configured tsearch stemming dictionary, which on my system is:

```
regress=> SHOW default_text_search_config;
 default_text_search_config 
----------------------------
 pg_catalog.english
(1 row)
```

so it's really doing:

```
regress=> SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'frightening') @@ to_tsquery('english', 'frightened');
 t
(1 row)
```

Let's look at each side separately:

which is comparing:

```
regress=> SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'frightening'), to_tsquery('english', 'frightened');
 to_tsvector  | to_tsquery 
--------------+------------
 'frighten':1 | 'frighten'
```

See what it's done? It's taken the words and trimmed them down to their root, or stem, using rules for the English language. Which is why they match.

So really, the `@@` operator with text values is just shorthand. In your case there *is* no index, because no index is required, though having one might make things faster. If you `explain analyze` the query, you'll see that it's still just doing a plain old seqscan.

Hopefully this'll help you understand what's going on. I'm not sure - I'm relying on understanding of concepts like data types and operator overloading that may or may not be familiar to you, and I'm intentionally skipping over some bits that require explanations that'd just be more confusing (like how exactly to tell what the different `@@` operators do).